Jetpack Compose CRUD application views don't refresh
I'm new to Android Compose. I'm generally teaching my daughter how to code and we decided to start with something that has an UI,so we chose Android to start. I made an app in Jetpack Compose and I have an error that I don't understand. Everything works as expected, but after the application goes into the background, it stops working properly. The application is simple - a simple CRUD on a database. The problem arises when I switch to another application and return to it after a while when I use other apps. Then the operations of creating an entry and editing it do not work, and the list does not refresh.  I tried to keep the common standards I use every day, like dependency injections, common layout, etc. Perhaps my habits from .NET programming or React are implemented differently in Compose.
Code is available here:
https://github.com/rnest-technoir/tne-todo
I tried to create simple and easy to grasp CRUD app. The app has Koin as DI, viewmodel and compose navigation on board. I tried to debug, and saw that add and update repository methods are called, but database is not updated. It all happens when I return to the application from the background.
I manually test the application in the standard way and all is good. On the other hand, when I use the 3 navigation keys on the bottom bar - the round one in particular and exit the application, go to another application and launch it. Then I go back to the debugged one and try to edit the list entry, there is no error in logcat and the room db despite the live edit remains unchanged, as does the list.
My navigation looks like this:
@Composable
fun AppOutlet(){
    val navController = Router.current
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Routes.taskListRoute){
        composable(route = Routes.taskListRoute){
            TaskListPage()
        }
        composable(route = Routes.taskAddRoute){
            TaskAddPage()
        }

        composable(route = "${Routes.taskEditRoute}/{taskId}", arguments = listOf(navArgument("taskId") { type = NavType.IntType })){
            stack -> TaskEditPage(stack.arguments?.getInt("taskId") ?: 0)
        }
    }
}

NavController is distributed across whole app via ComposisionLocal feature:
val Router = compositionLocalOf<NavHostController> { error("No nav controller!") }
And here is main screen of the app:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MainPage(viewModel: SharedViewModel = koinViewModel()) {

    CompositionLocalProvider(Router provides rememberNavController()) {

        val router = Router.current

        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            viewModel.initialize()
        }

        BackHandler {
            router.navigate(Routes.taskListRoute)
        }

        Scaffold(
            modifier = Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar(
                    title = { Text(text = "Top bar", color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF)) },
                    colors = topAppBarColors(containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary)
                )
            },
            floatingActionButton = {
                FloatingActionButton(onClick = { router.navigate(Routes.taskAddRoute) }, shape = CircleShape) {
                    Icon(Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "Add", tint = Color.White)
                }
            },
        ) { innerPadding ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
                ) {
                    // content here
                    AppOutlet()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Screen for task creation
@Composable
fun TaskAddPage(viewModel: SharedViewModel = koinViewModel()){

    val router = Router.current
    val context = LocalContext.current

    fun handleSubmit(task: TodoTask){
        val isValid = viewModel.validateTaskForm(task)
        if(!isValid){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid form", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }
        viewModel.addTask(task)
        router.navigate(Routes.taskListRoute)
    }

    Surface (
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(20.dp)
    ) {
        Column (
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
        ) {
            TaskForm(null) {
                handleSubmit(it)
            }
        }
    }
}

And create form itself:
@Composable
fun TaskForm(task: TodoTask?, onSubmit: (task: TodoTask) -> Unit){

    var title by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(task?.title ?: "") }
    var description by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(task?.description ?: "") }
    var priority by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(task?.priority ?: Priority.None) }
    var expanded by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    OutlinedTextField(value = title, label = { Text(text = "Title") }, onValueChange = { title = it })

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

    OutlinedTextField(value = description, label = { Text(text = "Description") }, onValueChange = { description = it })

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

    Box (
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentSize(Alignment.TopStart)
    ) {
        Row (
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .size(20.dp)
                .clip(CircleShape)
                .background(priority.color))
            Text(text = "Select priority")
            IconButton(onClick = { expanded = !expanded }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.MoreVert,
                    contentDescription = "More"
                )
            }
        }
    }

    Spacer(Modifier.height(10.dp))
    Row {
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            modifier = Modifier,
            offset = DpOffset(150.dp, 10.dp)
        ) {
            Priority.entries.map {
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = { Text(text = it.name) },
                    onClick = { priority = it },
                    leadingIcon = { Box(modifier = Modifier
                        .size(20.dp)
                        .clip(CircleShape)
                        .background(it.color)) }
                )
                HorizontalDivider()
            }
        }
    }

    Spacer(Modifier.height(10.dp))

    IconButton(onClick = { onSubmit(TodoTask(title, description, priority, task?.id ?: 0)) }, modifier = Modifier) {
        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Save, contentDescription = "Save item", tint = Color.Gray)
    }
}

Basically the same is for update screen.
My first idea was something is wrong with the navigation, but the issue persists even when I corrected the code and used events in add and create composables.
I develop the app on Windows 11 Pro, Android Studio Koala and connected via usb Nubia 7.

I strongly suggest to use Compose Destination github library. Its very robust and easy to implement.  Here's its link

There are two things that look different in your code to how I normally do things
Firstly. Rather than update the state value directly within your viewmodel you should copy a value to it and I normally use a custom class with properties representing individual state objects. That way your task list and current task become properties of a state object. Then to update a property of the state objects use:
_state.update { it ->
       it.copy(alltasks = newvalue)
}

Next in your activity you should create a state variable that equals viewmodel.collectAsState rather than expose the state objects directly from your viewmodel. This way you are using the viewmodels APIs to store and pipe updates to your UI.
Finally I would normally use a Factory to create the viewmodels but I'm not sure this is your problem
I would suggest you try the first two and see how it goes.
